# Finding out a specific amount of bytes being sent/received in a message. (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, packets

Here's a simple python 3.x TCP server:

```
import socketserver

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print(str(self.client_address[0]) + " wrote: " + str(self.data.decode()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

and client:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

while( True ):
    data = input("Msg: ")

    if data == "exit()":
        print("Exiting...")
        sock.close()
        exit();

    sock.sendall(bytes(data, "utf-8"))

#numBytes = ....?
#print("Sent: " + str( numBytes ) + " bytes\n")
```

I can't figure out how to view the exact number of bytes that I send in a message.  I can use len(data), but it doesn't account for the null terminator and such....  Is null terminator being sent as well, or is it irrelevant?  I tried researching on an exact byte count of a sent/received message, but I couldn't find any python-specific documentation and only have seen examples of people using len(), which I don't think is exact...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no null terminator in Python strings. If you want to send one, you have to do it explicitly: `sock.sendall(bytes(data, "utf-8") + b'\0')`.

However, there's no good reason to add a null terminator in the first place, unless you're planning to use it as a delimiter between messages. (Note that this won't work for general Python strings, because they're allowed to include null bytes in the middle… but it will work fine for real human-readable text, of course.)

Using null bytes as a delimiter is not a bad idea… but your existing code needs to actually handle that. You can't just call `recv(1024)` and assume it's a whole message; you have to keep calling `recv(1024)` in a loop and appending to a buffer until you find a null—and then save everything after that null for the next time through the loop.

---

Anyway, the `sendall` method doesn't return the number of bytes sent because it always sends exactly the bytes you gave it (unless there's an error, in which case is raises). So:

```
buf = bytes(data, "utf-8") + b'\0'
sock.sendall(buf)
bytes_sent = len(buf)
```

And on the server side, you might want to write a NullTerminatedHandler class like this:

```
class NullTerminatedHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = b''
    def handle(self):
        self.buf += self.request.recv(1024)
        messages = self.buf.split(b'\0')
        for message in messages[:-1]:
            self.handle_message(message)
        self.buf = self.buf[:-1]
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
class MyTCPHandler(NullTerminatedHandler):
    def handle_message(self, message):
        print(str(self.client_address[0]) + " wrote: " + str(message.decode()))
```

---

While we're at it, you've got some Unicode/string issues. From most serious to least:

- You should almost never just call `decode` with no argument. If you're sending UTF-8 data on one side, always explicitly `decode('utf-8')` on the other.
- The `decode` method is guaranteed to return a `str`, so writing `str(message.decode())` just makes your code confusing.
- There's a reason the sample code uses `format` instead of calling `str` on a bunch of objects and concatenating them—it's usually a lot easier to read.
- It's generally more readable to say `data.encode('utf-8')` than `bytes(data, 'utf-8')`.

Comment: Hmm, so in python perspective, len(buf), without the null terminator being added to it, is an accurate measurement of its byte size?

Comment: @Noobacode: Yes, if you're sending a bytes named `buf` without appending a null terminator, `len(buf)` is the length of the buffer. If, for whatever reason, you're explicitly adding a null terminator, `len(buf + b'\0')` is the length of the buffer with the null terminator.

Comment: @Noobacode: Just keep in mind that this is the length in bytes, not the length in characters. If you want _that_, use `len(s)` before encoding `s` to UTF-8.

Comment: @Noobacode: Yes.  Python3 makes explicit the difference between a byte string and text (hence the encode/decode), but even in Python2, `len('\0\0')` is still 2, for instance.

Comment: @abarnert so, is there a way to distinguish specifically between the two?  For example:  test shows up as 4 characters in length and 4 bytes in length....

Comment: @Noobacode: If you're dealing with a `bytes` (or `str` in Python 2, which is the same thing), `len` is always length in bytes—which may  be length in characters if they're all ASCII, but may be more. If you're dealing with a `unicode` (or `str` in Python 3, which is the same thing), `len` is always in characters; there is no "byte length" until you pick an encoding. If you want the length of a `bytes` in characters, `decode` it to `unicode` with the appropriate encoding; if you want the length of a `unicode` in bytes, `encode` it to `bytes` with the appropriate encoding.

Comment: @abarnert oh, thank you so very much, I definitely appreciate you taking your time to explain this to me :)